# How to convert table Yes/No attributes into binary data?

Tags: python, pandas, binary

I have the house voting data table. I want to covert the 16 attributes with Y/N in them to binary data. How can I get all data converted, I searched the website, most of time just convert one column. I want to have short code which can covert all attributes at a time.

[image]

Comment: do you use module `pandas` or something different ?

Comment: Yes, i use pandas. I am new in Python. I can covert one attribute at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `replace` with a `dict`:

```
df = df.replace({'y': 1, 'n': -1, '?': 0})
```

Comment: I tried this: df.replace({'y': 1, 'n': -1, '?': 0})
                 print(df.head()) but it did not print out the binary.

Comment: @jilimy `df = df.replace({'y': 1, 'n': 0})` ?

Comment: @jilimy You need to perform assignment to the result, or else pass `inplace=True`.

Comment: I wan to replace yes with 1, and no with -1, and '?' in the table means not agree or disagree, I want to set as 0. But It seems do not work.

Comment: This is what I leanred from other websites, but only got one column replaced at a time. df.infants[df.infants == 'y'] = 1
df.infants[df.infants == 'n'] = -1
df.infants[df.infants == '?'] = 0
print(df.head())

Comment: @jilimy What do you mean it does not work? When I try it on the data you provided, it works fine. Have you reassigned to the result of the `replace` call?

Comment: @jilimy If my answer worked for you, you can click the tick mark below the vote score to accept it so that others who run into this problem will know that it actually has a solution!